# Can't link datasource of two tablesView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

So I have two TableView in one view of an iOS app. I have connected the delegate of both tableViews to the ViewController, and the app works. The problem is when I connect to the viewController the dataSource, so when I run the app Xcode returns to me a SIGABRT. 
Anyonoe knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide some code, where does it crash?

Comment: When it is loading the xib where the two tableveiws are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the tableViews are not pointing to delegates that don't exist anymore. For example you might have deleted a delegate from your code but forgot to delete the connection from the tableview to the delegate.

Can you post your code?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{

}


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *Listview;
```

Comment: But the problem is with the datasource, the delegates are OK.

Comment: kk sorry, did you check the weither or not if the tableviews were pointing to a not existing datasource?

Comment: One thing: is there some specific code for datasource? (maybe I forgot it)

Comment: Are you using storyboard? If so you need to right click the tableview, and drag it to the .h file (a pop up will appear, you will need to name it). Then you need to right click the tableview and drag it to the orange circle with a square in it(it's the bar at the bottom of your view in the storyboard).

Comment: I'm working with Automatic Reference Countig, so I can't use weak in the @property.

Comment: Yea you can.My whole project is with Automatic Reference Counting. don't copy the "@property" Just right click on the tableview and drag it to the .h file. Then name it and it will make a property for you.

Comment: Ok. So I've done it and it doesn't work. But do you know what's the worst thing? I have made a new Xcode project with two tableView, setting all the delegates and datasources and they work! Why not in my main project if it is THE SAME CODE? Is possible that is it a Xcode bug?

Comment: it could be, but can't you just drag everything over to the new project?

Comment: Ok! I found why it doesn't work. The two tableviews are in a .xib, not in a .storyboard, that's the difference! The question is: what I have to change so?

Comment: right-click where your folders are, and add new file. then add a storyboard.